# prettier settings for vscode

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

I recently switched to a new computer, and am having difficulty with a prettier setting. (I think it's prettier, could be eslint).

This gif illustrates what's happening:
http://g.recordit.co/H871hfT9Sv.gif

Anyone know what this setting is called? I would prefer all imports to be on a single line unless the length extends the `printWidth` setting.

Here are my relevant User Settings from VS Code:

```json
{
  "prettier.printWidth": 100,
  "prettier.semi": false,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.trailingComma": "all"
}
```

Thanks !

Edit:
Visual depiction so you don't need to watch the gif.

Expected:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
import { isIphoneX } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper'
```

Behavior: (unwanted)

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
import {
  isIphoneX
} from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper'
```

Answer (score 97):

For those trying to **quickly change Prettier settings** for VS Code. Here are the steps:

1. Go to FILE -> PREFERENCES -> SETTINGS. (VS Code Menus)
2. Settings window should open. Above (Top) there is a search. Type "Prettier"
3. You should see the available Prettier settings. You can modify them :)

Comment: For me, the Prettier doesn't appear in the list there but my code is still formated by it ... you have any idea why I cannot see it in the list?

Comment: you didn't answer the question!! @nikhil patel's answer did work for me!

Comment: `You can use VS Code settings to configure prettier. Settings will be read from (listed by priority) `: from prettier details page. So you just need to edit VScode editor setting, Prettier will auto pick them

Comment: @P.Lorand, you're probably using the "Prettier-Standard" extension; uninstall it and install "Prettier - Code Formatter"

Comment: the problem i am having is that vs code keeps forgetting about `.prettierrc` config file. even though it is still in config path setting. so when i run "yarn prettier" i get one formatting, but when i save in VS code it re-formats it

Comment: prettier is my default formatter, but it looks like other formatters like typescript are fighting over things like spaces

Answer (score 50):

**The new way to configure prettier settings:**

1. at the root of your project folder, create a new config file (I'd suggest calling it either `.prettierrc.json` or just `.prettierrc`)
2. in that new file, add json custom settings: my go-to settings for JS are as follows:

```json
{
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

I'd suggest doing this in each of your projects and including in any source control, that way every pull of the repo will automatically set some base settings for that developer's instance of prettier.

Comment: Here is the link https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: You'll have to restart VSCode for it to take effect.  See this link for the config options: http://json.schemastore.org/prettierrc

Answer (score 14):

I had issue with formatting in VS Code. It was taking extension settings from prettier.

I did the following setting ins `.vscode/settings.json`

1. created `.prettierrc.json` file in root of the project
2. Installed `npm install --save-dev prettier`

These settings worked for me in VS Code.

.vscode/settings.json

```json
{
 "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,  
  "prettier.useEditorConfig": false,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc.json",
}
```

.prettierrc.json

```json
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[image]

`ctrl + ,`
paste --> `Prettier: Require Config`
uncheck it, then all done.

Answer (score 4):

These two steps helped me to set up the `.prettierrc` file correctly

1- Go to VsCode settings and check `formate on save`
[image]

2- Go to VsCode `settings.json` and set the defaultFormatter
`"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. To fix this, go into your prettier extension settings and look for "Print Width". Mine was set to '80'. I changed it to '100' and it all fit on one line after I saved the file. You can change the width to whatever you would like.

Answer (score 0):

If Prettier isn't showing up in your VS Code Settings, the extension may have silently crashed, which happens often when settings are changed in multiple places (i.e. tab size was changed in workspace as well as in settings).

Restart VS Code, and search for Prettier again, it should show up this time :)

Answer (score 0):

create .prettierrc file in the project dir, and use following code.

```
    {
  "printWidth": 100,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.json for vscode

```
    "prettier.configPath": "frontend/.prettierrc",
```

Or in the UI

[image]

This allows you to work from a root directory and still use prettier from a sub folder