# How to make "Prettier" the default formatter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I've installed *Prettier* extension in VS Code, and when I attempt to format a file, VS Code asked me:

> Do you want to format with the default formatter or with prettier formatter?

I accidentally chose the default formatter. How can I change this to format with *Prettier* as default?

Comment: [Quick Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53419053/14300162) I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Don't know why but setting Default Formatter to ebsenp.prettier didn't work for me. But I found a similar command that worked.

1. ctrl + shift + p
2. Format document with
3. Configure default formatter
4. Choose prettier

Comment: no longer working in version 1.74.3

Comment: @TanveerHossainJony, I've checked and still works

Comment: working in version 1.78.0

Answer (score 87):

1. Open settings by clicking the cog in the bottom left of the vs code side bar and selecting settings from the menu, or by hitting Ctrl+,
2. At the top right of the settings pane, hit the open file icon (if you hover, the tooltip will read 'Open Settings (JSON)'
3. Add the following line to the settings json:

   `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: For Prettier ESLint v5.0.4 from Rebecca Vest, use this setting instead: 
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"
}

Answer (score 30):

The easiest method I found was this:

1. Right-Click on a file you wish to format
2. Select

   ```
   Format Document With ...
   ```

[image: right-click menu]

---

3. You will be offered a drop-down of different formatters. The final entry will be

   ```
   Configure Default Formatter...
   ```

[image: formatter drop-down]

---

4. After your selection, if you repeat, you will see the default formatter marked with

   ```
   (default)
   ```

Comment: I read some many (I guess too many) answers for choosing a formatter and still didn't understand it properly, but this answer definitely gets it work reliably!

Answer (score 16):

1. Update the vs code if necessary.
2. Make sure that you have prettier extension and enabled it.
3. Go to setting by clicking ctrl with comma(,) that opens search setting bar.
4. There search for default editor
5. Select `default formatter` and choose `Prettier - Code formatter`

[image: default formatter - Prettier]

6. Search for `Format on Save` and tick the check box

[image: format on save checked]

7. `Note:` `shift + alt + f` also does formatting but without saving document.

[image]

8. This should work, else please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

In the command palette(ctrl + shift + p), search for format and then choose Format Document. Then choose Prettier - Code Formatter.

Note: If you do not see a prompt for selecting a default format, you can manually change this in your Settings. Set Editor: Default Formatter to ebsenp.

here is the compelete solution:
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-format-code-with-prettier-in-visual-studio-code#:~:text=In%20the%20command%20palette%2C%20search,and%20then%20choose%20Format%20Document.&text=Then%20choose%20Prettier%20%2D%20Code%20Formatter,Editor%3A%20Default%20Formatter%20to%20ebsenp](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-format-code-with-prettier-in-visual-studio-code#:%7E:text=In%20the%20command%20palette%2C%20search,and%20then%20choose%20Format%20Document.&text=Then%20choose%20Prettier%20%2D%20Code%20Formatter,Editor%3A%20Default%20Formatter%20to%20ebsenp).