# Visual Studio Code - Format Selection/Document not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I select the code, right click and chose Format Selection/Document nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to configure default formatter for your selected part or document.
Popular extensions for code formatting include Prettier, ESLint, and Beautify.

Comment: I have Prettier but how to do that?

Comment: probably a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63954584/11107541

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure Prettier, Just open your workspace or user settings in Visual Studio Code `Ctrl+` or `Cmd+` and add the following configuration for Prettier.

```
"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

Format the entire document :  `Shift+Alt+F`.

Format a selection: `Shift+Alt+A`.