# It is not possible to select prettier as the default formatting tool

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I have two projects, both vue projects, but one project says I can't use prettier as a formatting tool, and the other one works

You can see the screenshot below for details

The following two images indicate that the prettier is not recognized

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BLvu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPAA1.png)

The image below is another project that would normally have prettier selected as the default formatting tool
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox0Qn.png)

Where do I need to start with this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make "Prettier" the default formatter in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954584/how-to-make-prettier-the-default-formatter-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to select prettier as default formatting tool.
Open the Settings dialog ( Ctrl Alt 0S ), go to Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Prettier. Select Manual Prettier configuration and then select the Run on 'Reformat Code' action checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set default by `editor.action.formatDocument.multiple` (it's a key) button + click which you want have as default, then you can trigger your default formatting tool by `editor.action.formatDocument` button

Or you can append your config, so in `C:\Users\Yes\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json` I have:

```json
{
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "prettier.enabledLanguageIds": [
        "css",
        // ...more
        "javascript",
        "yaml"
    ],
}
```

*and make sure you have modern version of vscode(I have 1.85.0), because they once broke the updater by separating "system setup" and "user setup"*

to solve this, just over_re_install vscode